# speed meter in android

Tags: android, angle

I want to make speed meter in android .. the idea is just simple on imageView click the second imageView will be rotate by 45 degree. but problem is that the second imageView not rotate around fix point .... can any one suggest me what is do

```
public class BloodPressureActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btnImgBoy;
ImageView imgVNeddleBoy;
private int currentAngle = 0;
private int numOfAngle = 7;
Animation anim, zoomAnim;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_pressure);
    btnImgBoy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBollenBoy);
    imgVNeddleBoy = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewNeddlBoy);
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.back_rotation);
    zoomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_anim);
    // anim.setFillAfter(true);

    btnImgBoy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // rotate image view neddle
            btnImgBoy.startAnimation(zoomAnim);
            currentAngle++;
            currentAngle = currentAngle % numOfAngle;
            switch (currentAngle) {
            case 0:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(45);
                break;
            case 1:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(90);
                break;
            case 2:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(135);
                break;
            case 3:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(180);
                break;
            case 4:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(225);
                break;
            case 5:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(270);
                break;
            case 6:
                imgVNeddleBoy.setRotation(315);
                imgVNeddleBoy.startAnimation(anim);

                break;

            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setPivotX`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX%28float%29) and [`setPivotY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotY%28float%29) to set the centre of the rotation. This also sets the centre for scale.